# Maya/Arnold scripting, rendering ambient occlusion to the map using arnold utilities

Tags: python, maya

I using the following action to generate ambient occlusion maps for models in `maya`:

1. Create and assign `aiAmbientOcclusion` to my model (the one I want to generate oa maps for).
2. Then, I go *Arnold>Utilities>Render* Selection To Texture.

Since this process is always the same I want to write a python script to automate it unfortunately I haven't found many useful examples about writing scripts for Arnold.

To add this functionality I must:

```
import mtoa.renderToTexture
```

that script is located in

```
the_way_to_my_install_folder/solidangle/mtoa/2017/scripts/mtoa
```

I saw that the script defines the class `MtoARenderToTexture` and I should pass an object to it. Now.

What kind of object I mush use and is there some sort of documentation for MtoARenderToTexture class?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do what I wanted using ether [this tutorial](http://www.samwirch.com/blog/importing-and-running-external-python-scripts-maya-2011) and extending MtoARenderToTexture class.

I do not iclude all my scripts that load scene and manage scenes files as they very specific to my needs, but still think it's a good idea to share some very basic and fundamental elements that may be useful for some new entries as myself.

This is how my extended class looks like

```
import mtoa.renderToTexture as renderToTexture
import maya.cmds as cmds
class rkMtoaRtoT(renderToTexture.MtoARenderToTexture):

    def __init__(self):
        renderToTexture.MtoARenderToTexture.__init__(self)
        self.dFolder = '~'
        self.dResolution = 1024
        self.dCameraSamples = 5

    def doAutomaticExport(self):
        renderToTexture.MtoARenderToTexture.create(self)

        cmds.textFieldButtonGrp('outputFolder', e=True, tx=self.dFolder)
        cmds.intFieldGrp('resolution', e=True, v1=self.dResolution)
        cmds.intFieldGrp('aa_samples', e=True, v1=self.dCameraSamples)

        renderToTexture.MtoARenderToTexture.doExport(self)
```